# Add IF ELSE Condition in PL SQL stored procedure

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql

I have a scenario where I want to add an `IF ELSE` condition in my below procedure:

I tried like below but it is not getting compiled

```
PROCEDURE VSAT_EXCEL_REPORT
(
 P_R4GSTATE IN NVARCHAR2,
 TBLDATA OUT SYS_REFCURSOR
 )
  AS
  BEGIN

OPEN TBLDATA FOR    

    IF P_R4GSTATE = "ALL"

    THEN           
SELECT ENB.SAP_ID AS SAP_ID,CAND.CANDIDATEID AS CANDIDATE_ID,ENB.R4G_STATE AS STATE,ENB.SITE_TYPE AS SITE_TYPE,CAND.SITENAME AS SITE_NAME
 ,ENB.SITEID AS SITEID,ENB.PRIORITY_SITE AS PRIORITYSITE,ENB.CIRCLE AS CIRCLE,    
 DECODE (VTS.STATUS_NAME, null, 'Fill VSAT form', VTS.STATUS_NAME) AS STATUS,
        ENB.LATITUDE
       ,ENB.LONGITUDE
      ,VT.SITE_DETAILS_TECHNOLOGY
      ,VT.SITE_DETAILS_MOUNT_TYPE
      ,VT.SITE_DETAILS_ANTENNA_SIZE
      ,VT.SITE_DETAILS_AMSL        
      ,VT.SITE_DETAILS_PLATFORM_REQUIRED
      ,VT.SITE_DETAILS_PLATFORM_HEIGHT  
      ,VT.SITE_DETAILS_ROOFTOP_SITE     
      ,VT.SITE_DETAILS_NOOFLOORS        
      ,VT.SITE_DETAILS_ADD_ROOFTOP_SITE 
      ,VT.SITE_DETAILS_STRUCTURAL_STAB  
      ,VT.SITE_DETAILS_HEIGHT_OF_ANTENNA
      ,VT.SITE_DETAILS_SATELLITE_BAND   
      ,VT.ANTENNA_DISTANCE_NEAR_AIRPORT 
      ,VT.ANTENNA_AIRPORT_NAME          
      ,VT.GSAT_LOS_16_55E               
      ,VT.GSAT_LOS_18_74E               
      ,VT.GSAT_LOS_12_83E 
 FROM R4G_OSP.ENODEB ENB
INNER JOIN R4G_OSP.CANDIDATE CAND ON ENB.SAP_ID = CAND.SAP_ID 
LEFT JOIN TBL_VSAT_MST_DETAIL VT ON ENB.SAP_ID = VT.SAP_ID
LEFT JOIN TBL_VSAT_STATUS_MST VTS ON VT.STATUS_ID = VTS.STATUS_ID
WHERE ENB.SCOPE = 'EnodeB-Connected_MW'
AND ENB.SITEBACKHAUL = 'MW'
AND CAND.STATUS = 'Fill Vendor Survey Form' 
AND UPPER(STATE) IN 
(SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR(UPPER(P_R4GSTATE),'[^,]+', 1, LEVEL) AS RFIELDS FROM DUAL
                                          CONNECT BY REGEXP_SUBSTR(UPPER(P_R4GSTATE), '[^,]+', 1, LEVEL) IS NOT NULL);

                                          ELSE
                                          --Some condtion
  END VSAT_EXCEL_REPORT;
```

Comment: `OPEN cursor FOR   sql_statement` allows only SQL-statements. You can't place `IF` here, like `OPEN cursor FOR  IF...ELSE..END` it's syntactically incorrect, see the documentation for [OPEN-FOR](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14261/openfor_statement.htm)

Comment: @krokodilko: then how to do that in `plsql`

Comment: Please explain what you are trying to do. For now there is only a non-working codde snippet in your question. It's hard to guess looking on bad code what it is supposed to do.

Comment: @krokodilko: See, I want to show all the data if `ALL` selected from front end using stored procedure else show only the relevant selected data. SO i am trying to use `SP` for this scenario.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it should be image like this:

```
procedure VSAT_EXCEL_REPORT
(
  P_R4GSTATE in nvarchar2,
  TBLDATA    out sys_refcursor
) as
begin

  if P_R4GSTATE = 'ALL' then
    open TBLDATA for
      select ENB.SAP_ID as SAP_ID
            ,CAND.CANDIDATEID as CANDIDATE_ID
            ,ENB.R4G_STATE as STATE
            ,ENB.SITE_TYPE as SITE_TYPE
            ,CAND.SITENAME as SITE_NAME
            ,ENB.SITEID as SITEID
            ,ENB.PRIORITY_SITE as PRIORITYSITE
            ,ENB.CIRCLE as CIRCLE
            ,DECODE(VTS.STATUS_NAME
                   ,null
                   ,'Fill VSAT form'
                   ,VTS.STATUS_NAME) as STATUS
            ,ENB.LATITUDE
            ,ENB.LONGITUDE
            ,VT.SITE_DETAILS_TECHNOLOGY
            ,VT.SITE_DETAILS_MOUNT_TYPE
            ,VT.SITE_DETAILS_ANTENNA_SIZE
            ,VT.SITE_DETAILS_AMSL
            ,VT.SITE_DETAILS_PLATFORM_REQUIRED
            ,VT.SITE_DETAILS_PLATFORM_HEIGHT
            ,VT.SITE_DETAILS_ROOFTOP_SITE
            ,VT.SITE_DETAILS_NOOFLOORS
            ,VT.SITE_DETAILS_ADD_ROOFTOP_SITE
            ,VT.SITE_DETAILS_STRUCTURAL_STAB
            ,VT.SITE_DETAILS_HEIGHT_OF_ANTENNA
            ,VT.SITE_DETAILS_SATELLITE_BAND
            ,VT.ANTENNA_DISTANCE_NEAR_AIRPORT
            ,VT.ANTENNA_AIRPORT_NAME
            ,VT.GSAT_LOS_16_55E
            ,VT.GSAT_LOS_18_74E
            ,VT.GSAT_LOS_12_83E
      from R4G_OSP.ENODEB ENB
      inner join R4G_OSP.CANDIDATE CAND
      on ENB.SAP_ID = CAND.SAP_ID
      left join TBL_VSAT_MST_DETAIL VT
      on ENB.SAP_ID = VT.SAP_ID
      left join TBL_VSAT_STATUS_MST VTS
      on VT.STATUS_ID = VTS.STATUS_ID
      where ENB.SCOPE = 'EnodeB-Connected_MW'
            and ENB.SITEBACKHAUL = 'MW'
            and CAND.STATUS = 'Fill Vendor Survey Form'
            and
            UPPER(STATE) in
            (select REGEXP_SUBSTR(UPPER(P_R4GSTATE), '[^,]+', 1, level) as RFIELDS
             from DUAL
             connect by REGEXP_SUBSTR(UPPER(P_R4GSTATE), '[^,]+', 1, level) is not null);
  else
    open TBLDATA for
      select * from dual;
  end if;
end VSAT_EXCEL_REPORT;
```

Comment: getting error as `Error(1405,20): PLS-00201: identifier 'ALL' must be declared`

Comment: use 'ALL' instead "ALL"

Comment: now getting error as `Error(1396,22): PLS-00320: the declaration of the type of this expression is incomplete or malformed`

Comment: will let you know.